# What's a good opposite of "keep track"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, verbs, phrase-requests, antonyms

How can I say the opposite of "keep track"? I was trying to keep track of something but something happened and I lost the track.

I'd like to say "lose track".  Is it possible to say it this way or is it just my funny attempt to speak English? :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, *[lose track of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+track)* is quite a common phrase:

> to lose contact with someone; to forget where something is. *I lost track of all my friends from high school. Tom has lost track of his glasses again.*

Comment: Perhaps the most common usage is 'lose track of time' meaning to not realize how late it is.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can say 'lose track'. It doesn't sound funny.

Answer (score 4):

"Lose track" is perfectly acceptable, in the sense of misplacing or losing contact information or forgetting what you meant to be doing, but in the sense of "something happened and [you] lost [a thought]", you might rather say you were *distracted* by other thoughts, or *sidetracked* by other activities.

A colloquial phrase for *being lost track of* is "[*dropping off the radar*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+drop+off+the+radar)".  [See my *Update 1* comment]

Comment: You "drop off the radar" if you/your activities cease to be noticed by others. If *something drops off your radar*, you've made a concious decision not to bother with it. These aren't the same as *losing track*, which is normally something you do accidentally and/or without noticing.

Comment: Note that "dropping off the radar" describes the thing that you lose track of, like "[lost in the shuffle](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lost+in+the+shuffle)". *I lost track of time and didn't water the plants* or *I lost track of what I was doing when you called* (you lose track of something); but *Watering the plants just got lost in the shuffle* (the activity, watering the plants, gets lost) or *I was so busy, watering the plants dropped off my radar* (the activity drops off the radar).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that *I never hear from him anymore; he dropped off the radar* describes not being noticed, and I would equate this to the more familiar "dropped off the grid" or [dropped off the map](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drop+off+the+map) as in, *I can't find her contact information anywhere; she's dropped off the grid*. While not the same as *losing track* I think it's useful to point out that they're used similarly when talking about things like a friend you're no longer in touch with.

Comment: Your *dropped off the grid* sounds a bit odd to me. So does *dropped off the map*, to be honest, but at least [NGrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=dropped+off+the+radar%2Cdropped+off+the+grid%2Cdropped+off+the+map&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) agrees that one does actually get used often enough.

Comment: Update 1 revised "for losing track" to "for being lost track of" in last sentence

Comment: @FumbleFingers perhaps dropping off grids and maps is something that only exists in my dialect of American English! It looks that way from a few web searches, and the dictionary entry refers to the Cambridge Dictionary of American idioms.